# What is the assetlinks.json file for, when using Android deep links?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to get deep links to work in my app.

From what I read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html), it is enough to add an Intent filter to the app. I tried that and it works fine:

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
         <data android:scheme="http"
               android:host="www.example.com"
               android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
     </intent-filter>
```

Reading about "digital asset links" over [here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started), it says:

> Website A declares that links to its site should open in a designated
>   app on mobile devices, if the app is installed.

This involves uploading an `assetlinks.json` to my server.

But I cannot see the benefit of doing this if the intent filter already opens my app, so what is the point?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting from [a different piece of documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html):

> Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an app to designate itself as the default handler of a given type of link. If the user doesn't want the app to be the default handler, they can override this behavior from Settings.
>
> Automatic handling of links requires the cooperation of app developers and website owners. A developer must configure their app to declare associations with one or more websites, and to request that the system verify those associations. A website owner must, in turn, provide that verification by publishing a Digital Asset Links file. A Digital Asset Links file is a collection of statements conforming to the Asset Links protocol that make public, verifiable assertions about other apps or websites.

Right now, with your `<intent-filter>`, if the user clicks on a link to `http://www.example.com/gizmos`, they should see a chooser, offering to view that content in your app, available Web browsers, etc. With `assetlinks.json`, on Android 6.0+, you can prove ownership over that domain, and that will cause Android to (by default) bypass the chooser and drive straight to your app.

Comment: assetlinks will help you in case of supporting applinks and instanapps

Comment: do you know what would be the expected behaviour if our web app doesn't have native apps? I saw these requests being made by the bot. should we just ignore or put an empty json? I couldnt find information about this case

Comment: @user2472368: "I saw these requests being made by the bot" -- if you mean requests for `assetlinks.json`, I would expect you to return a 404 if you do not have a resource for that path. That is fairly standard Web behavior.

Comment: @bostan what do you mean by supporting applinks and instantapps, could you drop a link that describes more on that? I am trying to generate a url that can launch both instantapps and applinks but not sure whether deep links help with that.